# Parsing large JSON file using symfony controller

Tags: json, symfony, parsing, batch-processing, guzzle

I have a large json file (not in size, but in elements). It has 30000 JSON elements and I am trying to produce Entities from it as it reads it.

So far I have it reading the file with Guzzle, and it ends up producing about 1500 entities before it crashes. I feel that I must be doing this the wrong way.

Here is my code:

```
public function generateEntities(Request $request, $number)
{
$client  = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'http://www.example.com/file.json');
$promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
    $batchSize = 20;
    $i         = 0;
    foreach (json_decode($response->getBody()) as $entityItem) {
        $entity = new Entity();
        $entity->setEntityItem($entityItem->string);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
            $em->flush(); // Executes all updates
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $em->flush();
});
$promise->wait();
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('show_entities'));
}
```

I worked out from research that I should be clearing the Entity Manager frequently, so I added in batch sizing etc to flush it every 20 entities created. This did help but is not enough to load the full 30000 files.

Maybe I am completely wrong and should be handling it a different way?

Is it possible for someone to please point me in the right direction, I am happy to work it out on my own I am just a little unsure where to proceed from here.

Thank you!

Comment: First, I would move the code to Symfony Console Command. Console commands are not constrained by memory limit (afaik), and thus should be able to give you more time to finish. Do you need action controller for any particular reason?

Comment: @JovanPerovic Thank you for your reply. No I just thought it was the best way to handle it (only started using Symfony Recently). I don't need it to do anything but load it all into the database.

Comment: Overall, your approach seems sound. I know that that this makes Doctrine part obsolete, but have you thought about using `DBAL` instead of `ORM `? Basically, you would construct your own queries instead of entities. Personally, I am very fond of that method when hauling large quantity of data over...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could improve your process act in two ways:

1) **increment the time limit** of the execution of the controller action with the function [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), so put this as first line of the controller:

```
public function generateEntities(Request $request, $number)
{
  set_time_limit(0); // set to zero, no time limit is imposed
```

2) **Free much memory is possible** for each interaction flush the data to the database and detach/free memory as follow:

```
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush($entity);
    $em->detach($entity);
    $em->clear($entity);
    unset($entity);
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

The script is running out of memory because every one of the 30000 entities is managed in memory. You need to detach the entities from the manager periodically to make sure they are "garbage collected". Use `$em->clear();` in your batch flushing block to ensure memory isn't exhausted. See the [Doctrine page on batch operations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html) for more information.

Keep in mind though, that `$em->clear()` will detach all entities from the manager, not just those you are using in this loop.